# LoadRunner param array manipulation

Tags: loadrunner

I want to change one member of param array generated by web_reg_save_param_ex, for example, after executing

```
web_reg_save_param_ex("ParamName=City","LB=>","RB=</option>","Ordinal=All",LAST);
```

I would like to change {City_1} parameter.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lr_save_string(
     "Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyll-llantysiliogogogoch",
     "City_1"
);
```